# Image as custom icon inside Tab Navigation options not working React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using Tab Navigation in my react native application. In Tab navigation i have different screens for each tab and i wan to use custom svg image as icon for the tab. I have used build in MaterialCommunityIcons in following way and its working fine.

```
<Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: 'white',  // Color of tab when pressed
                inactiveTintColor: '#ebebf5', // Color of tab when not pressed
                showIcon: 'true', // Shows an icon for both iOS and Android
                showLabel: true, //No label for Android
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 11,
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'black', // Makes Android tab bar white instead of standard blue
                    height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 48 : 50 
                }
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Chat"
                component={LogsScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Chat',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons
                            name="chat"
                            color={color}
                            size={size}
                        />
                    ),
                }} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

but when i use image tab inside options prop in following way image is not being shown.

```
<Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: 'white',  // Color of tab when pressed
                inactiveTintColor: '#ebebf5', // Color of tab when not pressed
                showIcon: 'true', // Shows an icon for both iOS and Android
                showLabel: true, //No label for Android
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 11,
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'black', // Makes Android tab bar white instead of standard blue
                    height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 48 : 50
                }
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Feed',
                    tabBar: {
                        icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                            <Image
                                source={require('./Partie.svg')}
                                style={{ width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: tintColor }}
                            />
                        ),
                    },                      
                }} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I wanted to ask if it is valid to use Image inside options prop? and if not why so because apparently Icon and other icon related components are working fine inside this prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#options) I dont see any option for `tabBar` especially `tabBar.icon`. The valid option is `tabBarIcon` like the first piece of code above. Did you mistakenly adding this prop or do it on purpose?

Try:

```js
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <Image
                                source={require('./Partie.svg')}
                                style={{ width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: color }}
                            />
                    )
```

Comment: i have tired to use `tabBarIcon` as well but its not working either, i am not getting any error but image is not displaying as well

Comment: There might be something wrong with the image rendering by svg file, have you tried using an online image yet?

Comment: yes svg was not right, it is working with correct image.Thank you.